# For Each iteration doesn't work for HTTP GET request JSON, but does for initialized JSON

Tags: json, azure, azure-logic-apps

I'm very new with the Logic Apps, so sorry if I don't know how to express something properly.

GOAL: Take each of the items (berries) and modify them a little and then send them back in a JSON format.

PROBLEM: For Each section of the Consumption Logic Apps is not iterating through data coming from the HTTP Request's query via JSON parser, but it is working, if I input that same JSON data into a variable, and use it from there.

I have the following JSON file, coming in from HTTP request (GET) in the payload section:

```
{
   "berries": [
      "Strawberry",
      "Blueberry",
      "Poisonous Berry"
   ]
}
```

And I have put this to the schema generator, and got the following schema, for the HTTP Request GET Schema:

```
{
    "properties": {
        "berries": {
            "items": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "type": "array"
        }
    },
    "type": "object"
}
```

I have setup the HTTP Request (GET) as the first trigger like so:
[image]

Then, I use Parse JSON action, to get that JSON data, and to parse it out like this:

[image]

And the Schema is the same as is in the HTTP Get Request-section.

I noticed, that the output of this Parse JSON action is:

```
{   \"berries\": [      \"Strawberry\",      \"Blueberry\",      \"Poisonous Berry\"   ]}": ""
}
```

Which doesn't sound right.

The problem is, that when I try to iterate through these berries in the For Each loop, and save them to another array I have initialized like this:

[image]

I always get this error in the For Each section:
[image]

However, If I put that same piece of JSON data into initialized object, and then put that into the For Each via that same Parse JSON -action, everything works.

I'm out of ideas why is it that this is not working with the HTTP Request's Queries, but it is working for initialized values, since these should be the same. I've been testing this by clicking the Run Trigger > Run with payload and then put the JSON mentioned above into the Body-section, and hit Run. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ANSWER:

Ok, so the problem is, that I'm using GET as the HTTP Request method, not POST. I think GET method doesn't support JSON as payload, so to make this work, I must use POST, PUT, or (unofficial) SEARCH as the method. It is possible to use GET, but then, the queries-part of the request must be parsed manually to make it "true" JSON again for the actual parsers to understand it. Otherwise, the JSON parser in the Logic Apps parses it as one data field, and not as list of items.